# md-autocomplete translateY issue in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an issue with the md-autocomplete / md-virtual-repeat in Firefox. 
 When I Close and open md-autocomplete a few times the md-virtual-repeat at the end will become blank.
If you scroll in the blank container, the list items will appear again.
Anyone know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "md-virtual-repeat at the end will become blank" but I was having an issue that last items in `md-virtual-repeat` list were not appearing.

This happened because I was using `display: none / display: flex` to hide and show the element. I changed to use `visibility`.